# Flutter: type '(dynamic) => Text' is not a subtype of type '(DateTime) => String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, date, validation, dart

I want to get a start and end date from user, I used **`validator`** property but it gives me an error:

```
type '(dynamic) => Text' is not a subtype of type '(DateTime) => String'
```

my validator that I used in  `DateTimeField()`:

```
validator: (value){        
       if(value.isAfter(endDate)){return Text('please enter a valid date');}
       },
```

my method for validator:

```
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  void _trySubmit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); //close soft keyboard
    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
    }
  }
```

I want to know where is my error?

Comment: don't return a Text() widget as your validator error.  just return a String.  And is it really a DateTime in value?  If so, you might add typing information to your valdator callback.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz yes, there is a DateTime in value, I deleted Text() widget and now another error appears (The method 'validate' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: validate())

Answer (score 0):

*After removing the `text` widget your `validator` code should look like below*

```
validator: (value){        
       if(value.isAfter(endDate)){
         return "please enter a valid date";
       }
},
```

Comment: I have already deleted Text() widget and now another error appears (The method 'validate' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: validate())

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pass your _formkey in your textfield or Form, so  define it above the textfield or Form and pass it there

Comment: I didn't get it, can you explain it clearly?

Comment: The error `The method 'validate' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: validate()` indicates that currentState is null, which basically means that your GlobalKey<FormState> variable named '_formkey' is not wired up with your TextFormField or Form. You need to write Form(key: _formkey, child: etc)